# QTimer::singleShot equivalent for QML

Tags: qt, qml

Consider this C++ statement (example [from docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot)):

```
QTimer::singleShot(600000, &app, SLOT(quit()));
```

How to do the same in .qml JavaScript, something like this QML:

```
Rectangle {
    property int counter: 0
    onCounterChanged: {
        if (counter > 42) {
            // do equivalent of above C++ statement here
        }
    }
    // more code, which actually manipulates counter 
}
```

There's the obvious solution of having separate `Timer`, which is then started by this JavaScript code, and I'll accept that as an answer if a one-liner is not possible. Is it?

Comment: The equivalent would be [Timer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html). Set `repeat: false` to get single shot behavior.

Comment: `repeat` is *false* by default, actually.

Comment: Nice question. `setTimeout`/`setInterval` are out of question since they cannot be used. You can consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28514691/2538363) as a - rather hackish - approach. By setting parameters in function signature you can reduce the usage to a single line, e.g. `delay(/*repeat*/ true, 12000, functionName)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option I came up with is to simply define a function like this in C++:

```
void QmlUtils::singleShot(int msec, QJSValue callback)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(msec, this, [callback] () mutable {
        if (callback.isCallable())
            callback.call();
    });
}
```

and I call it from QML with:

```
lqtUtils.singleShot(5000, () => console.log("Hello!"))
```

In the callback you can access QML elements:

```
let abc = "Hello Luca!"
lqtUtils.singleShot(10000, function() {
    console.log(abc)
    myRect.color = "orange"
})
    
[...]
    
Rectangle {
    id: myRect
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "red"
}
```

I then added that C++ function to my collection of "must-have" here: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils/blob/master/lqtutils_ui.h#L53.

Comment: Would this work in case I wanted to work with some variables? Let's say  `lqtUtils.singleShot(5000, () => root.showNotification())` - can I reference objects like `root` in this example that are not "captured"(in terms of cpp lambda)?

Comment: I added another example. Is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 14):

I ended up adding this to my main.qml:

```
Component {
    id: delayCallerComponent
    Timer {
    }
}

function delayCall( interval, callback ) {
    var delayCaller = delayCallerComponent.createObject( null, { "interval": interval } );
    delayCaller.triggered.connect( function () {
        callback();
        delayCaller.destroy();
    } );
    delayCaller.start();
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
delayCall( 1000, function () { ... } );
```

Answer (score 12):

Change "repeat" property to false for Timer object.

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 600000
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: Qt.quit()
    }

    Rectangle {
        property int counter: 0
        onCounterChanged: {
            if (counter > 42) {
                timer.running = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it using a `SequentialAnimation` element:

```
SequentialAnimation {
    id: quitTimer
    PauseAnimation { duration: 60000 }
    ScriptAction { script: Qt.quit() }
}

Rectangle {
    property int counter: 0
    onCounterChanged: {
        if (counter > 42) {
            quitTimer.start()
        }
    }
}
```

If that's too ugly, make a component out of it:

```
// SingleshotTimer.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
SequentialAnimation {
    property alias delay: delayAnim.duration
    property alias script: scriptAction.script

    PauseAnimation { id: delayAnim; duration: 10000 }
    ScriptAction { id: scriptAction }
}
```

Using this new component gives what you want:

```
SingleshotTimer { id: timer; delay: 60000; script: Qt.quit() }

Rectangle {
    property int counter: 0
    onCounterChanged: {
        if (counter > 42) {
            timer.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a timer component in QML

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Timer {
        interval: 500; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: time.text = Date().toString()
    }

    Text { id: time }
}
```

for more details [see the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I set properties like this running: true; repeat: false;

```
    Timer {
      interval: 5000 
      running: true
      repeat: false
      onTriggered:console.log("Test");
    }
```